# Not Receiving Verbose Output From opkg

Tags: angstrom-linux, verbosity, opkg

When I run opkg update or opkg upgrade, it will pause for a few seconds, and then return to a new line.

```
root@device:~$opkg update
root@device:~$
```

I've tried running the command with the --verbosity=# command with the same results as above. Are there some settings that I might have messed up or improperly configured?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1) Did you try different verbose levels?

```
opkg -V 4 list                   --->  List available packages 
opkg -V 4 list-installed         --->  List installed packages
opkg -V 4 update                 --->  Update list of available packages
```

Take a look at opkg --help,

```
--verbosity <level>     Verbosity levels:                   

    0 errors only
    1 normal messages (default)
    2 informative messages
    3 debug
    4 debug level 2
```

Note:
opkg could list packages only if status file exists in opkg directory.
opkg status, repo, info...files and folders will be located at /var/lib/opkg/